# Yii2 Button with Parameter

Tags: php, yii2

I have this button in my Yii2 project:

```
Html::a('label', ['/attributes/index'], ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) ;
```

The button is located in the page:

```
/site/view
```

Now what I want to do is pass a parameter when this button gets clicked to the attributes/index page from the site/view page.

To be more specific it is the ID that I want to pass of a particular record from a DB I am viewing.

Cheers.

Comment: A quick view into the doc [Html::a()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#a%28%29-detail) tells you that the second parameter is used for URL generation ([Url::to()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl.html#to%28%29-detail)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass parameters as key => value pairs after the route:

```
Html::a('label', ['/attributes/index', 'id' => $id], ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) ;
```

See the Yii2 docs: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl.html#toRoute()-detail