# How to identify the two button clicks of the same form in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have two buttons  named search,create in the same form called search.How to identify these two button clicks in the controller function.

```
  <?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Search'), ['search'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
  <?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Create'), ['search'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
```

Comment: this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29227225/yii2-button-with-parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little strange what you are asking. But here goes nothing.

First you can always just add a parameter to the link, for example:

```
  <?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Search'), ['search', 'button' => 'search'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
  <?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Create'), ['search', 'button' => 'create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
```

This will create 2 different links and you can use the GET parameter to figure out what was clicked.

What I actually think you are trying to do is to submit a form. In Bootstrap the buttons and links look the same. You actually have 2 links, you do not have 2 buttons. The simple solution would just to turn those links into actual buttons and give them a name and a value.

```
<?= Html::button(Yii::t('app', 'Search'),
                    [
                        'name'=>'button',
                        'value'=>"search", 
                        'class' => 'btn btn-success'
                    ]
                )?>
<?= Html::button(Yii::t('app', 'Create'),
                    [
                        'name'=>'button',
                        'value'=>"create",
                        'class' => 'btn btn-success'
                    ]
                )?>
```

If your form is using GET to transmit data check the GET parameter to figure out what was clicked, otherwise use POST to figure out the same thing.

Comment: It's fine.But how I use it in the controller.                                                          if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post() ))

Comment: if(Yii::$app->request->post('button') == 'search') or if(Yii::$app->request->post('button') == 'create'), name it something better than 'button', maybe who_sent or something in those lines.

Comment: Got it.Thank you Mihai.